# Starter for Sump Pump

Tags: relay, fluid-pump, contactor

I'm trying to determine proper circuitry for starting a sump pump, but am unsure of what components I need. Originally was going to just use a relay, but have read suggestions for contactor+overload starter as well as start/run capacitors. Also not sure if this is dependent on what is already provided by the manufacturer, as some of the pumps I am using have thermal protection or pressure switches. The operation needs to be fast on/off.

Comment: Single-phase motors will often have two capacitors -- a start capacitor and a run capacitor. These are used for two different reasons. The start capacitor makes sure that the motor starts turning in the desired direction (for example, a table saw only wants the motor to turn in one particular way and not the other.) The run capacitor helps to reduce current peaks to/from the motor via your power line. (Three-phase motors don't need a start capacitor as the phases perform that job.) Overload protection helps avoid damaging the motor when other things don't work right -- jamming, for example.

Comment: Most single-phase motors I've bought already include a housing (needed to hold the capacitors) and the capacitors required for proper operation. So that's probably already there. Why don't you work with your sump pump suppliers, who know the product well, to see what else they recommend for long life and proper operation? I'd imagine they'd want to help. And we've no datasheet on your product, so it is hard for us to add much.

Comment: I use an on-off switch for my sump pump.